# How to get spell suggestions for numbers in marklogic spell:suggest api?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using spell:suggest-detailed api to get spell suggestions for a word. I have my own dictionary file, which also has numbers (year values). Is there a way i can get "2006" as a spell suggestion when i provide "200". Looks like this is not supported in existing Marklogic spell api. Is there a workaround to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the MarkLogic `spell:` API doesn't support words containing only numbers. As an alternative, you could use the Thesaurus API instead to manage expansion of those number-values:

```
import module namespace thsr = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/thesaurus"
  at "/MarkLogic/thesaurus.xqy";

thsr:expand(
  cts:word-query("200"), 
  thsr:lookup("/my-thesaurus.xml", "200"),
  (), (), ())
```